Attempting to decline request for re-evaluation after another user has voted as off-topic/duplicate fails
In the following scenario:

User asks question, is posted to Staging Ground
Question is placed into Requires Major changes status
Author edits question and requests re-evaluation
Another reviewer applies an off-topic vote

Attempting to review the question and choosing "Decline request for re-evaluation" (with the goal of returning the question to Major changes status) results in the following error message:

Declining reevaluation was unsuccessful. Please try again.

I encountered this problem once before, but I dismissed it as a transient issue. It has happened once again with this post.
I do not agree with the off-topic choice that another reviewer made and would prefer to place the question back into the "Requires major changes" status. I am aware that I can leave another comment and choose "Requires major changes" manually (which I did do in this case as I had no alternative), however, I do want this to come with the downsides that repeated requests for re-evaluation come with (if a question is repeatedly returned to the previous status via "Decline request for re-eval", the author can be temporarily locked out from requesting re-evaluation).
For those who cannot access the SG, here is how the post's timeline looks:

And here is what it looks like when I submit the attempt to decline the re-eval request:

